# C# LINQ select method to Java

Tags: java, c#, linq

I have been trying to translate this

```
                    var winner =
                    node.Connections.Where(n => n.HQ != null).GroupBy(n 
                    =>n.HQ)
                        .Select(g => new { Cantidate = g.Key, Count = 
                         g.Count() })
                        .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count)
                        .First()
                        .Cantidate;
```

to Java, although I am not sure I can achieve this with streams. I would like for someone to explain to me exactly what that code does or to help me translate this to Java.
I have been looking up to this resource: https://github.com/mythz/java-linq-examples/blob/master/README.md 
but I still cannot grasp what those lines of code do.

I understand first 3 lines, but the select gets me lost.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

After trying some code from help here, I got this:

```
Map<Candidate,List<Candidate>> winnersByWinner = node.getConnections().stream()
                    .map(Node::getHQ)
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity()));

winner = winnersByWinner.entrySet().stream()
                    .map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(e.getKey(), e.getValue().size()))
                    .sorted(new Comparator<AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<Candidate, Integer>>() {
                        @Override
                        public int compare(AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<Candidate, Integer> o1, AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<Candidate, Integer> o2) {
                            Integer o1v = o1.getValue();
                            Integer o2v = o2.getValue();
                            if(o1v==o2v) {
                                Integer o1k = o1.getKey().getId();
                                Integer o2k = o2.getKey().getId();
                                return o2k.compareTo(o1k);
                            }
                            return o1v.compareTo(o2v);
                        }
                    })
                    //.reversed())
                    //.sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry::getValue).reversed())
                    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                    .findFirst()
                    .orElseGet(null);
```

Thanks to Novaterata.

This:

```
candidates.Select(c => nodes.Count(n => n.HQ == c));
```

translates to:

```
candidates.stream().map(c -> nodes.stream().map(Node::getHQ).filter(c::equals).count())
```

Thanks to Novaterata again.

My code works now quite ok, but I have to edit to make sure of one last thing that I may have translated badly:

```
nodes.Where(n => n.Committes.Any()
```

translated to:

```
nodes.stream().filter(n -> !n.Committes.isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Is this correct?

Comment: That link doesn't have anything to do with Java streams.

Comment: You will need to replace Anonymous Objects with a simple private inner class with the same Fields

Comment: Try Map.Entry::getValue instead

Comment: Also, don't use == for equality unless it's a primitive or you are looking for the exact same object. Use .equals otherwise. I don't think HQ is a primitive is it? Or are you looking for the exact object?

Comment: `candidates.Select(c => nodes.Count(n => n.HQ == c));` would be `candidates.stream().map(c -> nodes.stream().map(Node::getHQ).filter(c::equals).count())`

Comment: I don't know how to fix this comparator, nothing I found works.

Comment: @Novaterata writing comparator worked, I edited the question with new code and I added one last small question about correctness

Comment: Yeah there's no way I could have known you had an Id property. My answer was based on what you'd provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is assuming node is a type Node with a getHQ() property. This is my approximation of what you'd need to do. Using SimpleImmutableEntry inplace of the anonymous type. I'd create a simple private class to replace that for readability. This gist is that groupBy will result in a Map that you you need to turn back into a stream with `.entrySet().stream()`  Map.Entry is very similar to KeyValuePair in C#.  Hopefully the rest is self-explanatory. Any method or Class I've used here, you should look it up.

```
   Map<HQ,List<HQ>> winnersByWinner = node.getConnection().stream()
            .map(Node::getHQ)
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity()))
   HQ winner = winndersByWinnder.entrySet().stream()
            .map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(e.getKey(), e.getValue().size()))
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Map.Entry::getValue).reversed())
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .findFirst()
            .orElseGet(null);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but actually that does not quite work. I've been trying to group it with collect(Collectors.groupingBy(...)) and after that map does not work "cannot resolve map(<lambda expression>)" and then there are issues with the SimpleImmutableEntry (cannot resolve methods getKey and getValue. Last, but not least, there is an error I've encountered many times trying to translate this: Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context.

Comment: Map and map are completely unrelated. Map is the same as IDictionary in C#, map is the same as Select. groupBy returns a Map, so you have to do entrySet().stream() to continue. Save it as a Map variable if it helps. Are you sure you are using JDK 8?

Comment: @KompiKompi my bad, I forgot to wrap groupBy in collect. I'm used to using joo-lambda which makes streams much more like Linq. You will probably like it, but I think you should learn plain streams first. https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL

Comment: @KompiKompi can you update your question with  java code you have tried? Including as much information about the types as possible

Comment: done. I'm still trying to figure something else out, but I keep getting this error

Answer (score 0):

Following is the explanation of the code.

```
var winner =node.Connections.Where(n => n.HQ != null) // this is checking the connection where HQ is not null
    .GroupBy(n=>n.HQ) // grouping based on HQ
    .Select(g => new { Cantidate = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }) // creating an enumerable anonymous type with cantidate , count
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count) // sorting this enumerable  type in type order based on the count
    .First() // take the first element from this enumerable type
    .Cantidate; // get the value of cantidate of that first element
```

This will be the equivalent SQL

```
(from n in connection 
                    where( n.HQ != null)
                    GroupBy(n.HQ) into g         
                    select new { Cantidate = g.key, Count = g.Count()}
                    orderby Count descending).First().Cantidate
```

Use the link which You have provide to convert it into java.

Comment: The `Select` is not creating a dictionary.  It's creating a enumerable of anonymous types.

Comment: Thank you, but I still don't know how to achieve this in Java